# Cypress Error: TypeError - cy.verifyDownload is not a function

Tags: cypress

I've been using cy-verify-download plugin for some time now. Today I've followed the guide described by dr. Gleb Bahmutov (https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-pdf/) and I've managed to get the pdf to html up and running. The problem is - the verify-download plugin stopped working and it throws the error as shown below.

[verify-download error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2clo.png)

I've tried clearing all but bare minimum from all of the files located in '.support/'. folder - no success. I've tried reinstalling verify-downloads plugin - nada. I have no idea what to do next and would be really grateful if someone could advise me on what to do, what went wrong and how to prevent it from happening with other plugins.

I'm attaching images of:

- [File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9BDb.png)
- [Commands.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IayAr.png)
- [e2e.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq5R0.png)
- [index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKqP6.png)
- [config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVDy5.png)

This is the code block where the error occured:

```
    it.only('Preuzimanje .pdf-a storniranog putnog naloga', () => {
        cy.get('.ant-switch-inner').click()
        cy.get('.ant-switch-inner').should('contain', 'ARHIVIRANI')
        cy.get('[placeholder="Pretraži"]').click().type(/*brojPN*/'PN 235/2023').type('{enter}')
        cy.get(".ant-table-tbody")
      .find(".ant-table-row")
      .eq(0)
      .then((dohvatButtona) => {
        cy.wrap(dohvatButtona).find(".download-button").click();
            imeDatoteke = "Putni nalog - " + Cypress.env("službeniPut_podatci").zaposlenik + " " +
          formattedToday + "..pdf";
        cy.verifyDownload(imeDatoteke);
        
      })

       })
```

Thank you in advance for all of your suggestions/help.

Comment: Please always copy paste code instead of posting image screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've managed to actually resolve this.

What I've done is I've deleted *supportFile: false* from the cypress.config.js and it worked just fine.